# How to hide form elements

Tags: codenameone

I am new to codenameone, how can i hide form element in a button click?

```
myButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
         //hide element
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the latest Codenameone plugin, you can do:

```
myButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        myElement.setHidden(true);
        myElement.getParent().animateLayout(200);
    }
}
```

**OR**

If the button has an actionEvent from GUI, do:

```
@Override
protected void onMyForm_MyButtonAction(Component c, ActionEvent event) {
   findMyElement(c).setHidden(true);
   findMyElement(c).getParent().animateLayout(200);
}
```

And to reveal it, do:

```
myElement.setHidden(false);
myElement.getParent().animateLayout(200);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use setVisible(boolean visible) (see https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/Component.html)

Comment: Visible prevents the component from being rendered but it still occupies the space https://www.codenameone.com/blog/hiding-url-security-advocacy.html